# Increase vertical mouse scroll wheel lines?

Tags: mouse, accessibility

When I mouse scroll wheel up / down it seems like I only "down arrow" 3 or 4 times. How do I double the amount of lines my mouse scroll wheel covers? It seems to be an elementary OS issue, and not a specific browser thing.

I desire to cover more distance with a vertical scroll wheel.

All Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Mouse > ??

[This is how you would change vertical scrolling # of lines](http://freewindowsvistatutorials.com/changeNumberOfLinesMouseWheelScrollsUpDownInWindows7.php) in Windows, but what about EOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, theres no option in the settings that I know which can achieve this. You can try setting manually,

> First check which device is the mouse:
>
> ```
> xinput list
> ```
>
> Now pick the ID of your mouse there, and list its current settings:
>
> ```
> xinput list-props <device-id>
> ```
>
> then change the settings like so where `Evdev scrolling distance
>   [vertical] [horizontal] [dial]`
>
> ```
> xinput set-prop <device-id> 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' 1 3 5
> ```
>
> where the combination of the last three numbers is mouse-dependent:
>
> - first number, the direction of scrolling (minus reverse)
> - second number, speed of scrolling somehow
> - third number, speed of scrolling somehow
> - Changing these values to bigger numbers means you scroll slower (AgentME).

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/709184/907048

Answer (score 1):

Hey there I wondered the same thing! and I hope that this starts to be something that makes it into the system settings some day. The reason being: that once you have set it up, it is out of the way and you don't think about it ever again.

I have used a different option that is a more straight forward slider that you can drag and set the speed.

I used [imwheel](http://imwheel.sourceforge.net/)

and followed these instructions
https://dev.to/bbavouzet/ubuntu-20-04-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed-536o

**How To**

*install* -> `sudo apt install imwheel`

*create the script file*. I use a folder for scripts `mkdir ~/Utils` where I created the file `touch mousewheel.sh` and pasted the [template](https://dev.to/bbavouzet/ubuntu-20-04-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed-536o) (section 2) in `vim ~/Utils/mousewheel.sh` then move to the script `cd ~/Utils/`

*make it executable* `chmod +x mousewheel.sh`

*run it* `./mousewheel.sh`

The scale is way too long, I use 5-7 depending on what I am doing.

*add it to the startup apps* there head to the
System Settings -> Applications -> Startup -> Add Startup App... (bottom left corner) and add it as a script, just `imwheel` or in my case `imwheel -b "4 5"` because the side buttons didn't work anymore and this fixes it

I hope this helps.

Comment: also what I like about this setup is, that it is easily reversible, just kill the imwheel process, or leave it out if the startup.